# Trying to decode a base64 String into a PDF, but the file is always corrupt. What am I doing incorrectly?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a pdf which has been encoded using base64. I am trying to take this encoded string, decode it, and save it to the phone as a pdf. The file saves as expected, but its unable to be opened because it is corrupted. I've tried different pdfs but still get the same result. Here is my code

```
val cachePath = File(context.cacheDir, "pdfs")
cachePath.mkdirs()

val stream = FileOutputStream(cachePath.path + "/$PATH_NAME")
stream.write(Base64.decode(inputString, Base64.DEFAULT))
stream.flush()
stream.close()

val file = File(cachePath, PATH_NAME)
FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"file_provider_authority",file)?.let {  uri ->
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    with(intent) {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
        data = (uri)
        type = context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "PDF"))
}
```